# Using the Central Limit Theorem to work out the approximate distribution of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are I.I.D $N(0,1)$. Then, what is the approximate distribution of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\,$?

I have the solution but none of it is making any sense to me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, there should be no capital N's

Comment: If $X$ is N(0,1), then $X^2$ has mean $1$, and its variance is $E[(X^2-1)^2]=E[X^4-2X^2+1]$. You should calculate this expectation. Once you have it you can get an approximate distribution.

Comment: How would the mean be 1? How would I calculate the variance without any data? I know the variance is $\frac{2}{n}$ but I don't know how they got there

Comment: Well you know $E[-2X^2+1]=-2E[X^2]+1=-1$. You just need to compute $E[X^4]$, which is a calculus problem.

Comment: Wouldn't $E[X^4] = 1?$

Comment: Nope. You need to actually compute the integral to see what you get.

Comment: I'm really confused, my knowledge of expectations is really limited, would you be able to offer another point?

Comment: You know the PDF is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$, so $E[X^4]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4 e^{-x^2/2} dx$. Computing this requires a bit of integration by parts.

Comment: I see! Can you confirm that the answer is in fact $\frac{2}{n}$ please?

Comment: I think $E[X^4]$ will turn out to be $3$, in which case $\frac{2}{n}$ would be the correct variance.

Comment: Also how does this make any use of the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: The calculations so far have nothing to do with the CLT, we have only computed the mean and variance. The CLT comes in when we say that if $n$ is reasonably large, our random variable has roughly *normal distribution* with that mean and variance.

Comment: So we can say that by the CLT, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\\$ is approximately normal with mean 1 and variance  $ \frac{2}{n} $ for a large n?

Comment: That is the way I had put it in the comment. It is a common but perhaps too casual way of putting it, since the CLT is a *limit* theorem and in principle says nothing about any specific $n$. And we did not say what roughly normal means. The result *can* be stated precisely, but for many applications the casual version is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard references will tell you that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ has a chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, and that distribution has expected value $n$ and variance $2n$.  Consequently the distribution of
$$
\frac{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2 - n}{\sqrt {2n}}
$$
is approximately $N(0,1)$.

To prove the assertions about the expectation and variance, it is enough to deal with $X_1^2$ and then multiply the expectation and variance by $n$.

Let $\varphi$ be the standard normal density
$$
\varphi(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(X_1^2) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \varphi(x)\,dx \\[10pt]
& = 2\int_0^\infty x^2 \varphi(x)\,dx & \text{by symmetry} \\[10pt]
& = \sqrt{\frac 2 \pi} \int_0^\infty x \left( e^{-x^2/2} (x\,dx) \right) \\[10pt]
& = \sqrt{\frac 2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \sqrt {2u}\, e^{-u}\,du \\[10pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty u^{\frac 3 2 -1} e^{-u}\,du \\[10pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt\pi} \Gamma\left( \frac 3 2 \right) = \frac 2 {\sqrt\pi}\,\frac 1 2 \Gamma\left( \frac 1 2 \right) = 1.
\end{align}

Similarly $\operatorname{E}(X_1^4) = 3$.  Therefore
$$
\operatorname{var}(X_1^2) = \operatorname{E}(X_1^4) - (\operatorname{E}(X_1^2))^2 = 3 - 1 = 2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use some "heuristics" to answer this questions. If $X_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then by definition $X_i^2\sim \chi^2(1)$, where $EY=1$, and $Var(Y)=2$. Denote $Y_i = X_{i}^2$, hence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^nX_i^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^nY_i$. Thus, for large enough $n$, ($n\to \infty$), you can use the CLT to deduce 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^nY_i \xrightarrow{D}\mathcal{N}(1, 2/n).
\end{align}